# Ubuntu won't boot on my chromebook after install

Tags: boot, uefi, chromebook

I have a Acer Chromebook C710 model Q1VZC. I originally thought I was going to install GalliumOS on it so I flashed MrChromebox's UEFI firmware before I found out my SandyBridge motherboard did not support Gallium. So I figured I already had UEFI so I figured I would install Ubuntu. I flashed a USB stick of Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop using Etcher, plugged it into the chromebook and did a clean install. Rebooted and it went straight to UEFI. Tried booting from hard drive. nothing. I booted a live version and installed it from Ubuntu. Rebooted. Nothing. I booted live Ubuntu and downloaded boot repair. Ran the recommended version and rebooted. Still nothing. Every time I tell UEFI to boot from the hard drive nothing happens. It goes straight back to the menu. I am a complete beginner so I am struggling to troubleshoot. Let me know what I need to do here.

Here is my boot info from Boot Repair: http://paste2.org/ZOf8Vvdk

Comment: So all you have on your chromebook that works right now is UEFI?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that Ubuntu (or GRUB rather) doesn't install the EFI boot loader in the default location where the MrChromebox UEFI firmware expects it. The fix is pretty simple. From https://mrchromebox.tech/#faq:

> Type 'exit' to return to the UEFI settings menu, then select Boot Maintenance   Manager. From there, select Boot From File, then navigate to and boot from /EFI/[distro name]/grubx64.efi (where [distro name] will be ubuntu, arch, debian, etc). Once your OS is booted, open a terminal/shell, and type the following (observing case):

```
sudo su
mkdir -p /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT
cp /boot/efi/EFI/[distro name from above]/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi
```

> then reboot to test. What we're doing is copying the grub EFI boot stub from the OS installed location to the location the firmware is expecting (/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi) on the EFI system partition (ESP), which most (Debian/Ubuntu-based?) distros will mount at /boot/efi. You may need to adjust slightly for your distro, but these instructions should work in most cases.